# Why is the first subplot skipped?

Tags: seaborn, data-visualization, subplot

I was trying to create visualize a variable using sns.distplot() and sns.boxplot()

[the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IZn8C.png)

I got this result:

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VXzIk.png)

Apparently,first subplot is skipped.Does anyone know why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are seeing the displot outside is because it is a figure-level function and you cannot use ax in it. You can change it to histplot and should see it working...

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(2,1,figsize=(5,5))
sns.histplot(wine['fixed acidity'], ax=axes[0])
sns.boxplot(wine['fixed acidity'], ax=axes[1])
```

**Plot**

[image]